# Counting spin degeneracies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Let's say that given an ensemble of $N$ spin-1 particles, I want to find the number of degeneracies. For this example, let's just assume that only the spin of the particle gives us degeneracies.

For $N=1$, this is easy since there are only three possibilities since spin-1 particles break into three other possibilities -1 or 0 or 1. For $N=2$, I count 6 degeneracies (-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1),(0,1). I want to be able to generalize this for $N$ particles. How about do I go about doing this?

Comment: The term "degeneracy" refers to the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue of a linear operator (the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to that eigenvalue), so either you mean something other than "degeneracy," or you need to specify an operator (likely a hamiltonian) for which you want to find degeneracies of certain eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your spin in generalized to be $s$. Then for $s=1$ you will have $(2+1)$ states (-1,0,1). So as well for as you have found it for 2 states. So generalization should be $N(2s+1)$.